# How to deploy a Java EE project to my webserver?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, glassfish

I'm working on my first Java EE project with NetBeans IDE. My application server is the integrated GlassFish.

At this moment my project run locally on my Mac with MySQL database. How can I deploy it on my web server?

Comment: What webserver do you have?

Comment: I have a apache webserver from all-inkl.com

Comment: As written in the question there is an integrated Glassfish available. You should use that one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339081/java-ee-7-glassfish-4-0-restful-webservices-using-and-netbean-and-deploying-on-g/18340894#18340894

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the remote application server functionalities of deploy.

If it's also Glassfish you can use the Administration Console to do it - e.g. example.com:4848 (defaut port for Glassfish admin portal).

Also you may use [Cargo Maven Plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) in order to automate the deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just create the war file and copy it to your web server. When you start your web-server it will automatically deploy the war file.

Comment: I have uploaded the war file and nothing happened ;(

Comment: Just throwing it out there: most servers can turn of auto deployment so this might not work depending on the setup.

Comment: which app server are you using ? If you are using tomcat; just copy the war file into webapps folder. If you have not made any configuration changes  at tomcat level; it will auto deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You have different possibilities:

- Netbeans can deploy your application on the integrated Glassfish server. This should happen automatically if you `Run` you project and the Glassfish server is selected for this project. You can change the selected server for every project under `Project Properties -> Run`
- You can deploy .war files via the Glassfish admin console if the Glassfish server is already started. Navigate to `http://localhost:4848`, go to `Applications` and click on `Deploy`
- You can manually deploy you applications. You have to copy either the .war file or a folder containing the contents of the .war file to the folder `/GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy`