# Java EE 7 GlassFish 4.0 Restful Webservices using and Netbean and deploying on Glassfish 4.0

Tags: web-services, netbeans-7, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I have followed [this Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) to Create simple Java EE 7 Webservices using Netbean 7.3.1. I have Glassfish 4.0 running with Netbeans. I ran project successfully without any problem.

Next Step is to Deploy Webservice project on standalone version of GlassFish 4.0 webserver. So I can run it without Netbeans.

Using Glassfish web interface on `http://localhost:4848`, and navigating

```
Common Taks -> Applications -> Deploy
```

I browse using ("packaged file to be uploaded to the server") and Select the CustomerDB.war file from my project's sub directory /dist/

I have created the war file by running project in Netbean.

But Deployment Failed with following Error.

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource Please see server.log for more details.
```

When I checked Server Log C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log

It says

```
[2013-08-20T16:15:07.633+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=33 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1377011707633] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource   ]]
```

**UPDATE:**

OK I find the solution of above problem as I forget to add the connection.
I just added Connection pool and connection resrouces.

Added JDBC connection pool by navigating `Common Tasks -> Resources -> JDBC -> JDBC Connection Pools`.

Added the connection Resources by navigating `Common Tasks -> Resources -> JDBC -> JDBC Resources`

But I am still getting error. This time it is different.

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [CustomerDB] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Any Idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Fix First problem, open your `glassfish-resource.xml` file from your project, it will look something like this. 
[image]

if you don't have glassfish-resource.xml in server-configuration folder you can also check the these details by clicking on services tab in netbeans and furhter clicking on connection pools as shown in this screenshot. 
[image]

Based on the information in it, and using Glassfish 4.0 web interface `http://localhost:4848`

Firstly Create new JDBC connection pool by navigating
Common Tasks -> Resources -> JDBC -> JDBC Connection Pools.
It will look something like this. 
[image]

[image]

Then Secondly  create Connection resource by navigating 
Common Tasks -> Resources -> JDBC -> JDBC Resources 
It will look somehting like this. 
[image]

First Problem is sorted. you can test it using Ping button in connection pools 
[image]

For Second problem. (if your ping is not successful do following)

Search `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` file in Netbeans installation folder and copy it to Glassfish library folder

```
C:\glassfish4\glassfish\lib
```

After copying stop & start server by running following commands in folder `C:\glassfish4\glassfish\bin`

```
asadmin.bat stop-domain domain1
asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
```

After above, deploy the application again and it will successfully deployed and you can access it using test interface
`http://localhost:8080/CustomerDB/test-resbeans.html` exactly the way as in netbeans.